# SQL ORDER BY one column then another

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, heidisql

So I'm joining two tables together and then I'm trying to order first by PID and then within PID order by Month. I can manage to get the query working and ordering by PID but when I try to order by month as well the query keeps running out of memory.

```
SELECT l.Name, l.PID, Z.Month
FROM Z
INNER JOIN l ON l.Name=Z.Name
ORDER BY l.PID, Z.Month ASC;
```

Desired output:

```
Bob, 1, 01
Bob, 1, 02
Bob, 1, 04
Gary, 2, 03
Gary, 2, 08
Louis, 3, 01
Louis, 3, 02
```

etc. Note how month is ordered inside of the PID order.
Both Month and PID are integers.

Comment: looks ok to me..Are you saying it works with just one order by element?

Comment: It looks good and it should work for both order by. Please provide the error you are getting

Comment: Weird, it runs when I limit it by 100. But it still takes several minutes to do so! I wonder why it's taking SO long just to order it by month?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using ("*keeps running out of memory*" sounds weird)

Comment: Are the names unique in each table?  Do the character sets and collations match?  How large are the tables?

Comment: I'm using HeidiSQL. Yeah everything is fine - I got it working by limiting the query to only return a few million rows at a time. The tables are 2GB and 500MB.